# Theme and color scheme of Area 51

Tags: discussion, area-51

The purpose of Area 51 is to propose new Stack Exchange sites that will attract experts in the particular area of interest.  It even states in the FAQ to ask real, expert questions.

Then why does the theme of Area 51 look like a bad Nickelodeon cartoon?

Comment: I think it looks awesome

Comment: Aliens can be professionals, too. I should know, I've worked with a few (dressed up as humans, of course.)

Answer (score 8):

People always accuse us of [not allowing fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) on these sites.

If [Metlife](http://www.metlife.com/) can have their Snoopy, if [Geico](http://www.geico.com/) can have their gecko, then we can love our little aliens.

[alt text http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:d4awtn3JN3iMgM:http://www.thesda.org/hrlu/Images/metlife.png](http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:d4awtn3JN3iMgM:http://www.thesda.org/hrlu/Images/metlife.png)[image][image] [image]

```
  Metlife       Geico      Stack Exchange     Clippy?
```

Comment: Where's Clippy?

Comment: @Robert Harvey - That's SO not a good example.

Comment: +1 in spite of that evil thing on the right.  The graphics are fantastic (IMHO).

Comment: I thought Meta was used as a place to crack wise about the other three sites. Looks what happens when you get a bunch of deprived developers in one area...waffles and unicorns...<sarcasm>just plain awesome!</sarcasm>

Answer (score 4):

Because they like little aliens.

Comment: There ya go. "Star" for reading the FAQ.

Comment: I read the FAQ too, but I do not get the correlation between aliens and a site for proposing Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Michael "New site staging zone"

Answer (score 3):

All I know is that I love the *evil unicorn* on the top banner in the [faq page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

[image]

Comment: You forgot the free-hand circle. >:O

Comment: Great...we need another place to talk about unicorns and waffles....